# Iterating through an Array with Controller As Syntax -AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller

I am currently have trouble displaying my array using the "Controller as" syntax if I pass the $scope in to my controller it works fine but using the "Controller as" syntax and this. My array does not appear on the page I'm just wondering if I am doing something wrong?

Here is the JSBin

http://jsbin.com/qufevalenoda/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Should be `<p ng-repeat="post in main.posts">{{ post }}</p>`

Comment: Ahhh thanks you!!! Anthony! Stupid little mistakes

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/qufevalenoda/3/edit

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
    {{ main.title }} <br> <br>
    {{ main.posts }}
    <p ng-repeat="post in main.posts">
        {{ post }}
    </p>
</div>
```